# Firebase custom login fails (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase-security

I'm trying to get started with firebase and now with the security part of it. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible in order to get started, using guides and code snippets from the Firebase website.

In order to keep it simple I have a webpage containing a password (id "Code") and user input field (id "Door"). How do I check if the password entered in field "Code" is equal to the password that is already stored in node https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/loapp_users/BAAJ/password, BAAJ being a userid of one of the users stored in node loapp_users, all with a child node "password"?

The code below doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // Monitoring User Authentication State

    // Use the onAuth() method to listen for changes in user authentication state

    // Create a callback which logs the current auth state
    function authDataCallback(authData) {
      if (authData) {
        console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
      } else {
        console.log("User is logged out");
      }
    }
    // Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
    var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com");
    ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);

    $("#logout").click(
        function logout() {
            ref.unauth();
            ref.offAuth(authDataCallback);
        }
    );

    // LOGIN
    // The code to authenticate a user varies by provider and transport method, but they all have similar signatures and 
    // accept a callback function. Use it to handle errors and process the results of a successful login.

    // Create a callback to handle the result of the authentication
    function authHandler(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
      }
    };

    $("#login").click(
        function() {
            var usersRef = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/loapp_users");
            // Authenticate users with a custom Firebase token
            var _user = $("#Door").val();
            var _level = "docent";
            var _password = $("#Code").val();
            var userRef = usersRef.child(_user);
            // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our user reference
            userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                console.log(snapshot.val());
                if (snapshot.val().child("password").text() == _password) {
                    ref.authWithCustomToken("eyJ0e....etc...mlhdCI6MTQyOTM4Mzc0M30.Vn1QF7cRC6nml8HB9NAzpQXJgq5lDrAie-zIHxtOmFk", authHandler);
                    } else {
                    console.log("Gebruikersnaam en code komen niet overeen")
                    }
                }, function (errorObject) {
                  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
                });
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
snapshot.val().child("password").text()
```

should instead be:

```
snaphot.val().password
```

Then it works.